# @sizeof throws a error with php8, how can I fix this

Tags: php

I use the follow code in PHP to check if the array is filled.

```
    if (@sizeof($mediaArray) > 0) { 
      Do something
    }
```

When the array is not filled I get this error in PHP8:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: sizeof(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in...

In php7 this was no problem. What can I do to fix this? How can I check if an Array is not empty?

Comment: The error says the variable is `null` so check that it's not null before using sizeof.

Comment: You can use the [`empty()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for that.

Comment: It's generally not recommended to use the error control operator (@) as a way to handle errors or warnings. It makes debugging more challenging because you're not aware of potential issues in your code like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `count()`

```
if (count($mediaArray) > 0) {
    Do something
}
```